# Django ModelChoiceField displaying values in django.contrib.auth and a Profile table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am extremely new to python or django. I inherited some code that needs some "fixing" and I could use some help.

Here's the situation:

We have a drop-down box from which you can choose multiple users. Currently, the users are displayed as usernames. We would like for them to be displayed as Full Names.

The Issue:
The username is coming from: `django.contrib.auth`

The First Name and Last Name are coming from the Profile Model. 
Here's what the Profile Model looks like:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
CURRENTLY_STUDENT = "STU"
CURRENTLY_PROFESSOR = "PFR"
CURRENTLY_CHOICES = [
    (CURRENTLY_STUDENT, "Student"),
    (CURRENTLY_PROFESSOR, "Professor"),
]

user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile")
currently_am = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=CURRENTLY_CHOICES, default=CURRENTLY_STUDENT)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

If you have to display a full name we use the following:

```
user.profile.display_name
```

where display_name is:

```
def display_name(self):
        name = "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
    return name
```

Following is the code for the drop-down box in forms.py:

```
 from django import forms
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 from account.utils import user_display


class UserMultipleChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):

def label_from_instance(self, obj):
    return user_display(obj)


class ShareForm(forms.Form):

participants = UserMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=User.objects.none(),
    label="",
    widget=forms.SelectMultiple(
        attrs={
            "data-placeholder": "Choose members.. "
        }
    )
)
```

Following is the code from account/utils.py for `user_display`

```
from account.conf import settings

def user_display(user):
return settings.ACCOUNT_USER_DISPLAY(user)
```

and here's the code from account/conf.py

```
class AccountAppConf(AppConf):
USER_DISPLAY = lambda user: user.username
```

- You can't use `obj.get_full_name()` as the First Name and Last Name are not coming from django.contrib.auth instead they are stored in the above mentioned Profile Model.
- You can't use return obj.profile.display_name() either as the ModelChoiceField is drawn on django.contrib.auth.

Could somebody please help me with this? How can I display full-names in the drop-down boxes and still pass the "user" as the value once someone makes a choice from the dropdown and hits submit?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can assign custom choices as:

```
choices = [(obj.id, obj.profile.display_name()) for obj in User.objects.all()]

participants = UserMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=User.objects.none(),
    label="",
    widget=forms.SelectMultiple(
        attrs={
            "data-placeholder": "Choose members.. "
        }
    ),
    choices=choices
)
```

Comment: Thanks Aamir. I really appreciate it :)